# jpeg not loading with Response.Outputstream on server

Tags: c#, asp.net

i'm working on an ASP.net 2.0 c# project where i am creating a basic Captcha script. the html looks like this:

```
<img height="30" width="80" alt="" src="Captcha.aspx" />
```

and here is the code behind for Captcha.aspx

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap objBMP = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(60, 20);
        Graphics objGraphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(objBMP);
        objGraphics.Clear( ColorTranslator.FromHtml( "#054196" ) );

        objGraphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;

        // configure the text
        Font objFont = new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Bold);
        string randomStr = "";
        int[] myIntArray = new int[5];
        int x;

        // randomise the text
        Random autoRand = new Random();

        for (x = 0; x < 5; x++)
        {
            myIntArray[x] = System.Convert.ToInt32(autoRand.Next(0, 9));
            randomStr += (myIntArray[x].ToString());
        }

        //add string to session
        Session.Add("randomStr", randomStr);

        // draw the text
        objGraphics.DrawString( randomStr, objFont, Brushes.White, 3, 3);

        // Set the content type and return the image
        Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        Encoder quality = Encoder.Quality;
        EncoderParameter qualityParam = new EncoderParameter(quality, 100L);
        EncoderParameters encParams = new EncoderParameters( 1 );
        encParams.Param[0] = qualityParam;
        ImageCodecInfo jpgEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        objBMP.Save(Response.OutputStream, jpgEncoder, encParams);

        objFont.Dispose();
        objGraphics.Dispose();
        objBMP.Dispose();
        Response.Flush();
    }


    private ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)
    {

        ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();

        foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)
        {
            if (codec.FormatID == format.Guid)
            {
                return codec;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

this works fine on my local machine, but when uploaded to our dev server it fails. i don't have direct access to the dev server to debug due to my role in the project so it's a bit of trial and error atm.

any ideas?

Comment: Can you at least use Fiddler or FireBug to check the request and the response (sometimes it happens in production enviroment that the URL is wrong and the request doesn't simply go where it's suppose to).

Comment: firebug spits out 'Image corrupt or truncated' in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out the server didn't like the aspx page for some reason. so i moved the captcha to a ashx file and then it worked!

Comment: or you could try putting `Response.End();` as the last line of `Page_load` to make it work.